# How can I call other methods from the current method?

Tags: aura, helper, function

I am trying to do this, but nothing works ... I am a beginner.

**//helper js**

```
getDataFromDB : function(component){
    let action = component.get('c.getListContacts');
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
       let state = response.getState();
           if (state === "SUCCESS") {
               let rows = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.contacts", rows);
            }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    this.calculateAmountPage(component);
    this.getDisplayDataPagination(component);
```

},

Methods "calculateAmountPage" and "getDisplayDataPagination" are located below in the same **helper.js** file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the helper reference to access those functions. To do so:

Accept the helper reference in the helper function

```
getDataFromDB : function(component, event, helper){
```

And pass it in by accepting the helper reference in the *controller* function. e.x.

```
onButtonClick : function(component, event, helper){
  getDataFromDB(component, event, helper);
}
```

Then call the other functions like this

```
helper.calculateAmountPage(component);
helper.getDisplayDataPagination(component);
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but my `getDataFromDB : function(component){` function is already in "helper.js". And from it I need to call other functions, which are also already in "helper.js". I know how to call the functions located in "helper.js" from the controller.

Comment: I cannot call all functions from helper.js from the controller, because they will run at the same time and I will get an error. I need to call a helper function, which in turn will call another helper function at the end of its execution.

Comment: Are you calling getDataFromDB from the controller? If so, pass in helper and then you will have a reference to all helper methods from within getDataFromDB (and you can in turn pass the helper reference to other helper functions)

Comment: Wow! With a little experimenting I got it. I understood. I didn't know it was possible! Thank you very much!